# Leaflet: click through marker's transparent background

Tags: leaflet, markers, svg

The icon I use on my marker does not cover the whole quadratic area.

[image]

Is there a way to be able to click through the transparent parts of the marker onto another marker or the map itself?

I'm using only SVGs as marker icons. So I thought of css `pointer-events`, but this didn't seem to work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it's overly complicated.

First, you'll need to capture the `click` event on the marker's icon, and [fetch the colour of the clicked pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751020/how-to-get-a-pixels-x-y-coordinate-color-from-an-image). Discard the RGB values, and compare the alpha value to a threshold.

Then, remove the marker's icon from the DOM, call `document.elementFromPoint` to know what's "behind" the marker's icon, re-add the icon to the DOM, create a synthetic `MouseEvent` (or `PointerEvent`) based on the original event, and dispatch it on the element behind. There is an in-depth explanation of this technique at ["Forwarding Mouse Events Through Layers"](https://web.archive.org/web/20161230064952/http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/).